# Elementary questions about factor spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ a vector space with $\dim V < \infty$ and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Let $V/U$ a factor space, i.e. $V/U:=\{[x]\mid x\in U\}$ with $[x]:=\{y\in V\mid x-y \in U\}$

I have four elementary questions.

$\bullet_1$ If $v,w\in V$. Is it true that $v\ne w$ iff $[v]\ne[w]$ ?

$\bullet_2 $ If $U=\{0\}$, then $V/U=P(V)$? ($P$ denotes the potence set)

$\bullet_3$ If $U=V$, then $V/U=\{V\}$ or $V/U=V$ ?

$\bullet_4$ $\{(x,y)\in V\times V\mid x+y\in U\}$ is a equivalence relation on $V$?

My thoughts:

According to $\bullet_1$: $'\Rightarrow'$ holds, but not $'\Leftarrow'$.

According to $\bullet_2$:, I think this is true since $[x]=\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\in W$ for any $W\subset P(V)$

According to $\bullet_3$: I would say $V/U=V$, since $\{V\}$ is not even a vector space.

According to $\bullet_4$: I know that $\{(x,y)\in V\times V\mid x-y\in U\}$ is a equivalence relation on $V$. And since $y\in V$ also $-y\in V$, thus this is the same?

I am absolutely not sure about factor spaces. Some enlightenment would be very helpful!

Comment: @DietrichBurde yes you are right, actually I meant the other way round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1: $\Leftarrow$ certainly holds, $\Rightarrow$ in general not. (But if $U=\{0\}$, ...)

Ad 2: In general, no. Instead $V/U=\{\,\{x\}\mid x\in V\,\}$. And as soon $V$ is not the 0-space, we can find distinct elements $x,y\in V$ and have $\{x,y\}\in P(V)$, but $\{x,y\}\notin V/U$.

Ad 3: $V/U=\{V\}$ is a one element set. Which is a zero-dimensional vector space.

Ad 4: In general, this is not an equivalence relation. For an equivalence relation, you'd need (among others) that it contains $(v,v)$ for all $v\in V$. But you cannot expect $2v\in U$ to hold for all $v\in V$. This is only true if either $U=V$ or we work in characteristic $2$.